# Uncaught Error: Objects are not valid as a React child but it's an array

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm very new to react trying to learn it by building a small app which displays ingredients based on button clicks.

In my recipe view component I'm trying to render multiple ingredient views however I'm getting this error:

> **Uncaught Error**: Objects are not valid as a React child (found: object with keys {ingred}). If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead.

My code is far from perfect, and it's difficult for me to try and explain the issue I can link you to my full application if you don't understand my explanation to see the error for yourself. Here's the relevant code:

```js
import React from 'react';
import IngredView from './IngredView'
import './styles/RecipeView.css';

const RecipeView = ( {recipe} ) => {
  const { recipe_name, set_ingredients } = recipe
  const isIngredDefined = (set_ingredients !== undefined)
  const ingred = isIngredDefined
  ? set_ingredients.map(set_ingredients => {
    return (
      <IngredView
        set_ingredients={set_ingredients}
      />
    );
  })
  : "none"
  console.log(ingred);
  return (
    <section className="recipe-view">
      <h1 className="recipe-name">{recipe_name}</h1>
      {set_ingredients !== undefined &&
        {ingred}
      }
    </section>
  )
}

export default RecipeView;
```

And here is my Ingredient View ( the console log was for debugging)

```js
import React from 'react';
import './styles/IngredView.css'

const IngredView = ({set_ingredients}) => {
  const { components } = set_ingredients[0]
  console.log(set_ingredients);
  return <section className="ingred-view"><img className="ingred-image" alt="comp" src={components[0]} /><img className="ingred-image" alt="comp" src={components[1]} /><img className="ingred-image" alt="comp" src={components[2]} /><img className="ingred-image" alt="comp" src={components[3]} /><img className="ingred-image" alt="comp" src={components[4]} /></section>
}

export default IngredView;
```

Comment: What is the `console.log(ingred)` displaying?

Comment: @theJuls https://i.gyazo.com/999d6c0371d3d285a6d0a3a55a0e31f8.png this is what it's displaying

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a couple things here that I can see right off the bat in your `RecipeView` component.

First of all, in it's `return` statement, you have `{set_ingredients !== undefined && {ingred} }`. The brackets surrounding `ingred` are incorrect. You are not allowed to have those brackets within them in such a manner in JS (well... You are technically allowed, but you are turning `ingred` into an object with `ingred` as an attribute, which I don't think was your intention and they cannot be rendered in React as the error being displayed to you suggests), so the correct statement would be `{set_ingredients !== undefined && ingred }`.

Secondly, still looking at that same statement. From what I can tell, your intention is to display `ingred` if `set_ingredients` is NOT `undefined` and nothing otherwise, is this correct? The way you are doing it is incorrect, since if the first condition is `false`, you will display `false`. React does not render boolean values. To fix this, I would use the [ternary operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator), which will make the statement look like this:

```
{set_ingredients !== undefined ? ingred : null }
```

In your `IngredView`, I am not sure what you are trying to do. You set your `components` variable as the first element from `set_ingredients`. This will only work if the object you are trying to deconstruct `components` from is from the first index of `set_ingredients`, which based off of the screenshot you showed me, is not the case. The correct way to do this, would simply be:

```
const { components } = set_ingredients
```

**So to sum it all up:**

- Remove the extra brackets from the return statements `RecipeView`. The result should be this:

  {set_ingredients !== undefined && ingred }
- Use the ternary operator instead of the `&&` statement in the above code:

  {set_ingredients !== undefined ? ingred : null }
- In `IngredView`, pull `components` out of the `set_ingredients` object, not the first index of it:

  const { components } = set_ingredients

Comment: You're a god! Thank you so much

Comment: Always happy to help :)